# A simple, yet effective, respirator

Tags: science-based, biology

These settlers live on a planet, which surface temperature and pressure are compatible with human life. However humans cannot breath its atmosphere. The gas in the atmosphere is not necessarily toxic or extremely dangerous (skin exposure is ok), but it will eventually kill a person (or maybe the atmosphere simply lacks oxygen).

So my people will need a "mask" to wander around. I want it to be as small and simple as possible, and would prefer if it leaves the mouth "free". I was actually thinking of some kind of nose respirator, but I guess it would make their voice funny.

How can I deliver breathable air to people with the minimum amount of hardware around their face?

Comment: Watch Cameron's Avatar for a mask just like what you describe. A radio inside the mask also provides long-range communication, while avoid funny voices.

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing what the specific problem with the atmosphere is. The solution to "there's just too much CO2/(other gas that's toxic above a certain partial pressure)" is quite different from "there isn't enough/any oxygen in the atmosphere", for example.

Comment: @Roughcoat It does not matter , I want them to recieve air only from the machine

Comment: You say "I want them to receive air only from the machine."  Are you talking like a SCUBA system or a rebreather?  Those are very different concepts than a respirator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Medical people already do that: a plastic tube that has a short T that fits in the nose. This is called a [Nasas Cannula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_cannula).

[image]

But more generally, there are masks and breathers of all "sizes" from this minimalism to full helmets, for all kinds of design requirements. You can find what you are looking for among real products.

Comment: This really doesn't work unless your people are good at not accidentally breathing through their mouths.  Also, you answer is pretty sparse...for example a link to or picture of what you are talking about may makes sense.  This feels comment-y

Comment: @James, the question said that the atmosphere was not toxic. People would just get dizzy, collapse and die eventually if they just use their mouth.

Comment: Without knowing "why" the atmosphere is not breathable, it is difficult to answer in a serious way. An atmosphere with too little oxygen might make this solution perfectly acceptable, but not one with too much carbon dioxide, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The exopack from [Avatar](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Exopack) is a lightweight atmosphere filtration system developed from civilian rebreather technology that allows humans to survive in conditions of unbreathable atmospheres with a minimum amount of equipment. It seems to perfectly meet your requirements. Added a same hatch in it would also allow for the mouth to remain free, while they couldn't breath at the same time its open of course.

[image]